# Upgrade 18.04 to 20.04 fails in both update manager and terminal commands

Tags: upgrade, update-manager, do-release-upgrade

When I try to update from Ubuntu 18.04 to 20.04 in the software updater it gets to "Fetching is complete," freezes, then after a couple of minutes closes.[image]

In terminal mode it does basically the same thing:

```
chas@chas-pc:~$ sudo do-release-upgrade
Checking for a new Ubuntu release
Get:1 Upgrade tool signature [1,554 B]                                         
Get:2 Upgrade tool [1,340 kB]                                                  
Fetched 1,342 kB in 0s (0 B/s)                                                 
authenticate 'focal.tar.gz' against 'focal.tar.gz.gpg' 
extracting 'focal.tar.gz'

Reading cache

Checking package manager
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree        
Reading state information... Done
Get:1 http://ro-mirrors.evowise.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease [242 kB]           
Hit http://ro-mirrors.evowise.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease              
Hit http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                     
Hit http://ro-mirrors.evowise.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease            
Hit http://ro-mirrors.evowise.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease             
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net/alexlarsson/flatpak/ubuntu bionic InRelease       
Ign http://repo.vivaldi.com/stable/deb stable InRelease                        
Hit http://repo.vivaldi.com/stable/deb stable Release                          
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net/dhor/myway/ubuntu bionic InRelease                
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net/eugenesan/ppa/ubuntu bionic InRelease             
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net/inkscape.dev/stable/ubuntu bionic InRelease       
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net/libreoffice/libreoffice-7-0/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net/libreoffice/ppa/ubuntu bionic InRelease           
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net/openjdk-r/ppa/ubuntu bionic InRelease             
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net/otto-kesselgulasch/gimp/ubuntu bionic InRelease   
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net/rednotebook/stable/ubuntu bionic InRelease        
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net/savoury1/digikam/ubuntu bionic InRelease          
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net/savoury1/ffmpeg4/ubuntu bionic InRelease          
Fetched 242 kB in 0s (0 B/s)                                                   
Reading package lists... Done    
Building dependency tree          
Reading state information... Done

Restoring original system state

Aborting
Reading package lists... Done    
Building dependency tree          
Reading state information... Done
chas@chas-pc:~$
```

I've repeated this many times, using every approach I can find on the Internet, with the same results.

Does anyone have any idea what is wrong?

Comment: Remove all PPA's and try again.

Comment: Removed PPAs and keys, no joy.

Comment: After removing all PPAs and doing some other clean-up, upgrade still fails. After